# How do I get value of cell before it changes in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This function seems not to be triggered until the cell is exited, as the value i'm getting is the post-change value.  I need the pre-change value, but I only need it if in fact that particular column is edited.

Thank you

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var columnNum = r.getColumn(); 
  var msg;

  if (columnNum == 11) {

    var dateCell = s.getRange(r.getRow(), 11); 
    var v=dateCell.getValue();
    msg = 'Value= ' + v;
    Browser.msgBox (msg);

    //dateCell.setValue(v);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but in case anyone else needs the answer, it's quite easy to get both the old and new values of any edited cell with the event object:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let oldValue = e.oldValue;
  let newValue = e.value;
  console.log("The range's old value was: " + oldValue + ", and the updated value is: " + newValue);
}
```

Here are are the accessible properties of the [Google Sheets event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, capturing the value of a cell before an edit is still not possible.

You might like to star [this issue on the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=200&q=onedit&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner); it is currently deemed a medium-priority enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

@AdamL  Is there anyway to access the spreadsheets revision history programmatically?

Sorry this is beyond my noob abilities, but my question may hold the clue to a workaround for A B's issue.

@A B  ANOTHER POSSIBLE WORKAROUND
You could set up a time based triggers to populate 2 arrays. 1 array from the current data in the column your checking for edits, and 1 array from a previous snapshot of the same data. Then by using a loop to test if any values have changed since your last trigger event, you can determine what value/values have changed(if any) If a value your testing for has changed then push the rowNumber() and colNumber() and getValue() of both previous and current instances of the same data to a new array, also include a timestamp new Date(). Have this new array data populate a new sheet or spreadsheet.

If used in conjunction with your onEdit function, yourll be able to see the before and after value changes, and the approximate time they occured.

Time based triggers can be set to run every minute, hour day etc